# What's behind the cat and mouse play of ISI and CIA?

Tags: united-states, pakistan, afghanistan, cia, intelligence-service

There are several reports about Pakistan's Inter-Services Intelligence (ISI) targeting the CIA ([example1](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/us/Pakistans-ISI-funded-deadly-attack-on-CIA-camp-in-Afghanistan-US-National-Security-Archive/articleshow/51819428.cms), [example2](http://www.npr.org/2011/03/08/134371381/Relations-Between-Pakistani-U-S-Intelligence-Agencies-Strained)). But why? I am sure there are specific interests of Pakistan involved in this. What are these interests ISI trying to protect?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I need to say something about the links you supplied.

**Example-1**: [Pakistan's ISI funded deadly attack on CIA camp in Afghanist: US national security archive](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/us/Pakistans-ISI-funded-deadly-attack-on-CIA-camp-in-Afghanistan-US-National-Security-Archive/articleshow/51819428.cms):

[image]

This is an Indian newspaper with a [right-center bias](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/times-of-india/), and the report is written by [Chidanand Rajghatta](https://www.linkedin.com/in/chidanand-rajghatta-553969/) who is stationed in the USA.

**Example-2**: [Relations Strained Between CIA, Pakistan's ISI](https://www.npr.org/2011/03/08/134371381/Relations-Between-Pakistani-U-S-Intelligence-Agencies-Strained)

[image]

This is a US media house.

So, my first opinion would be - in case of any news related to Pakistan - I won't take any decision **solely** by consulting these media reports. I would like to consult more news media outlets.

---

Any news coming from Afghanistan can be explained by [this source](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/19942/25524).

In essence, this is a power tussle between **{** Pakistan + Taliban **}** versus **{** Afghan Government aka Northern Alliance + USA + India **}**.

1. Taliba's aim is to capture power in Afghanistan as they are the dominant ethnic groups in Afghanistan.
2. Pakistan's aim is to have a favorable government in Afghanistan that doesn't maintain its alliance with India to create unrest in Pakistan.
3. Northern Alliance's aim is to keep the Taliban out of power by maintaining cooperation with India and milking the USA.
4. I don't know about the USA's aim in Afghanistan. Probably to surround Iran, but I am not sure.
5. India's aim is to keep a strong foothold in Afghanistan and continue a proxy war against Pakistan through various Afghan factions so that Pakistan remains busy, and doesn't talk about Kashmir much.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that having a pro-India or US-centric bias in no way refutes the notion that there is tension and conflict between those two specific agencies. You may want ISI to be cast in a different light, or for blame or responsibility to be cast in a different way, but that's not what the question is really about, IMO. It's well-known that the US feels factions within the ISI have their own sympathies and agendas that don't necessarily align with what the US is told by the official leaders of government, and will often withhold information because of that.

Comment: "Taliba's aim is to capture power in Afghanistan as they are the dominant ethnic groups in Afghanistan." That's a rather imprecise statement, as the Taliban is a political organization, not an ethnic group.